# Nee a code of API VBA to capture all handles of particular window by caption/Title

Tags: vba, api

I have search lot on the internet but I didn't find the solution. I need to get all API handles of particular window by caption/title of that window.

I have a code but it captures all handle of all open windows.

```
    Public Sub GetWindows()
    x = 0
    winOutputType.winHandle = 0
    winOutputType.winClass = 1
    winOutputType.winTitle = 2
    winOutputType.winHandleClass = 3
    winOutputType.winHandleTitle = 4
    winOutputType.winHandleClassTitle = 5

    GetWinInfo 0&, 0, winOutputType.winHandleClassTitle
End Sub
```

I need code that will ask me window name and then capture handles of that particular window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a duplicate for [Close all VBE windows (VB for Aplications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993444/close-all-vbe-windows-vb-for-aplications) but couldn't find a link. I ended up here. For future users looking for a similar query, this should help you/them.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Sub GetWindows()
    '~~> Pass Full Name or Partial Name. This is not case sensitive
    Debug.Print GetAllWindowHandles("Microsoft Visual Basic")
End Sub

Private Function GetAllWindowHandles(partialName As String)
    Dim hWnd As Long, lngRet As Long
    Dim strText As String

    hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)

    While hWnd <> 0
        strText = String$(100, Chr$(0))
        lngRet = GetWindowText(hWnd, strText, 100)

        If InStr(1, strText, partialName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "The Handle of the window is " & hWnd & " and " & vbNewLine & _
                        "The title of the window is " & Left$(strText, lngRet) & vbNewLine & _
                        "----------------------"
        End If

        '~~> Find next window  
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, hWnd, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: I get Type Mismatch in FindWindowEx, any ideas?

Comment: No. I'm running a 64-Bit machine

Comment: Change `Dim hWnd As Long, lngRet As Long` to `Dim hWnd As LongPtr, lngRet As LongPtr`