# Close all VBE windows (MS Access, VB for Aplications)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

If you are like me and you work with lots of code you probably hate to close all open VBE code windows one by one. There is no functionality in VBE which would do it. How to do it?

Comment: I just press and hold Ctrl+F4 for a few seconds. :) -- MZ-Tools also has functions for this.

Comment: Good point, but it closes also the window i am currently working with. I learned again... thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a duplicate for this question. I couldn't fine one. So I ended up at [Nee a code of API VBA to capture all handles of particular window by caption/Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917703/nee-a-code-of-api-vba-to-capture-all-handles-of-particular-window-by-caption-tit) and answering that as well :D

Well the logic is the same. Once you have the handle, simply close the window using `SendMessage`

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Const WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112
Const SC_CLOSE = &HF060

Public Sub GetWindows()
    '~~> Pass Full Name or Partial Name. This is not case sensitive
    Debug.Print GetAllWindowHandles("Microsoft Visual Basic")
End Sub

Private Function GetAllWindowHandles(partialName As String)
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr, lngRet As Long
    Dim strText As String

    hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)

    While hWnd <> 0
        strText = String$(100, Chr$(0))
        lngRet = GetWindowText(hWnd, strText, 100)

        If InStr(1, strText, partialName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            '~~> Close the window
            SendMessage hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0
        End If

        '~~> Find next window
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, hWnd, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Wend
End Function
```

The above code absolutely works. Screenshot below. Opened 3 VBEs (One for MS Word. One for MS Powerpoint and One for MS Excel) and all three closed.

[image]

Comment: Can we assume Vba7 (office => v14) as standard and use Ptrsafe as default declaration or is this too soon?

Comment: Updated..... :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: your code is very complicated and when I tried that nothing got closed. Compare it with simplicity of CloseVBEWindows.

Comment: I marked this solution as "very low quality" and hopefully the moderator will look at that.

Comment: @Vlado: **1.** The code is tried and tested **2.** It is not complicated. Too bad if you feel it is complicated. You downvoted becuase of that? Seriously? :D Anyways you are free to downvote or mark it as low quality.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: Sorry I did not see your edits. I have been out the whole day. Let me see your edits :)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: I do not see your edits? Can you share here? If valid, I will incorporate it :)

Comment: Restored edits, This is the source I use [Windows API Viewer for MS Excel](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: I made changes to 2 of them. Rest are ok. Since I do not have Office 64bit, I usually refer to https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp. If you can test the above in office 64, I will update it with the code that you tried :)

Comment: Just tested (Office 2013 x64), makes no diff what I used, worked all. But for sure  jkp-ads.com is wrong on [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) as `cch`should be same as returnval and refering to [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit) it should be Long type and [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) oMsg should be Long too.

Comment: Done! Rereading [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit) make me think that padding safes you, when using`LongPtr`on wrong args. Will only fail on two following wrong`LongPtr`s (as they are not padded then).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: there you go. approved.